# How should I organize my application?

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application, organization

I am currently working on a React/TypeScript project and have separated my files into a few folders. My project is solving Sudoku interactively, using various processing methods, and so I have split up my application into this structure:

```
sudokusolver/
    css/
    dist/
    fonts/
    img/
    js/ -> external libraries, ie. jquery, etc.
    node_modules/
    server/ -> fetches puzzle data from the server
    ts/
        actions/ -> user actions stored for history navigation
        components/
        containers/
        enumerations/
        models/ -> stores multiple actions for history navigation
        solver/ -> sudoku solving methods
        index.tsx
    index.html
    package.json
    ...
```

Right now, my `components/` and `containers/` folders are getting fairly large. I'm wondering what scheme I should follow for reorganizing my file structure, knowing that this is a single page application. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why `jquery` is not in `node_modules`? Why `css` is not next to components? Why `fonts` and `img` which are basically assets are not in a common directory? I would also start by creating a `ui` folder. Don't call folders `ts`. Why not call it simply `src` or `source`?

Comment: my js folder containers bootstrap, jquery, etc. But I guess npm could handle that anyway. Good point!

Comment: How exactly would having css next to components be helpful? The entire application is client side, with one php script for data access in the `server/` folder.

Comment: In a component based architecture every component should have its own separate styles. There is actually a movement to write styles entirely in react (javascript) code. That's why I am telling you that they should be next to component - because every component should have its own styles.

Comment: Ok. So how would this work with global styles? And how efficient is it at loading these styles compared to the global styles?

Comment: That's the point - there are no global styles. If you want to style a button, create a button component which internally uses that style.

Comment: Oh, ok. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you posted, it reads like your `component` and `container` folders are flat - I don't think that's a good idea - it will, as you say, lead to fairly lengthy folders.

One of my personal projects has the following layout. Under components, I have all my reusable components and component pieces. They're more or less nested arbitrarily - I'll have a "game" folder under modals, layout, , form, etc - just to help with clutter. "Containers" (as I understand them), are under "routes," and their folder structure follows the URL path that they're loaded agains (`/profile/games` uses containers/wrapper from `routes/profile/games/...`)

[image]

it would also help, in my opinion, to move everything not globally related to your project's build (i.e. everything but webpack definitions, npm's package.json, gulpfiles, (babel/eslint/tslint)rc files, etc) into a subfolder - `src` or similar.

I would also split your server and client applications - they don't need to be under the same folder. I usually do something like

```
projectname/
    project_client/
        # client src
    project_server/
        # server src
```

it will help cut down on clutter.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Also, just to clarify, this is just following the container/component layout, not having to do with routes, so the containers just hold the logic of the components. I think, following what you're saying, I should combine them and then break up everything into new folders by their hierarchy (on the page). That might also help a bit.

Comment: Yeah - this is just my personal style but I think it works well. Don't be afraid to nest folders - you can easily collapse/hide folders. And, like I said, I think my "routes" folder is like your "container" folder. Everything in routes just holds/places high-level components (like "place a grid of pictures here").

Comment: I would recommend to put `actions` and `reducers` into a common superfolder, e.g. `state`. Actually, some people prefer to keep actions and reducers into the same folder with files named such as `navigation.reducer.ts` and `navigation.actions.ts`. The reason is that those files are usually very tightly coupled and when editing one, you are usually also editing the second.

Comment: @Sulthan good point. I have all my actions and reducers separated (`actions/game.ts`, `reducers/game.ts`, `actions/modal.ts`, etc) so it made sense for me to put them into their own folders.